# Core Data: Inserting a new row after performing fetch

Tags: swift, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I'm having trouble figuring out this GCD problem.

Let's say there's one UITableViewCell in the table view. This cell has some text fields that the user is editing. After the user finishes editing, the cell creates a new object in Core Data based on what the user typed in. This object is inserted with `insertNewObjectForEntityForName`.

After this, I need to `performFetch` on the NSFetchedResultsController and reload the tableview. However, I also want to add a new cell to the end of the tableview, so the user can add another item to their list.

This is what I'm doing to try that:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    do {
        try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Fetch failed: \(error)")
    }

    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: self.fetchedResultsController.sections!.first!.numberOfObjects - 1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    self.tableView.reloadData() 
})
```

The new cell is added, but without the row animation. I think there's something I'm misunderstanding with GCD and Core Data. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try this:
`func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }
    
    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }`

Comment: @Santosh I tried those delegate methods, and the new cell is added with row animation. However, both cells are filled with the same data (implying that the table view still needs to be reloaded). When I scroll around the table view, the cells correct themselves (confirming that implication).

Comment: Yes keep your ` self.tableView.reloadData() ` as well after you do `insertRowAt..`.

Comment: Data problem fixed, but still no row animation. It's as if I never added the delegate methods at all.

Comment: You could also try this: 
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: self.fetchedResultsController.sections!.first!.numberOfObjects - 1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()

Remove those delegate methods and try only this.

Comment: @Santosh Doesn't work. Same effect as having delegate methods w/o reloadData(). Animation works, not data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115864/discussion-between-santosh-and-shaan-singh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by implementing:

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?)
```

Using a `switch` statement inside of this function allows for more control over each change that occurs:

```
switch type {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        print("Insert")
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        print("Delete")
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
        print("Update")
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
        print("Move")
}
```

Inside this switch, you can use the `indexPath` to remove cells, add cells, whatever you want. Just use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` or another relevant function.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use first closure as the thread process that running asynchronously. Once the process done, it will go into second closure which is on the main thread to do anything with your view

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

        // process here
        do {
            try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Fetch failed: \(error)")
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { Void in
            // then refresh UI
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: self.fetchedResultsController.sections!.first!.numberOfObjects - 1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

check this tutorial for details https://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1